# Using the Correct Windows Build Type

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to create a Windows mobile build for the Windows Appstore. I cannot find any tutorials or documentation for `Codename One` Windows mobile only release. My main question is which [build type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIL7n.png) should I choose in the `Codename One Windows Preferences`? Will the `Mobile Debug Build` work for me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long discussion about the various build targets for UWP in the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-uwp.html